# Install driver and copying files before Installation runs

Tags: visual-studio-2005, installation

I have created installation package for my project, but before or after installation is complete i need to install some drivers and copy some files to target machine, before my software can run. 
Is it possible for me to do all this action in the MSI installer setup project of visual studio 2005. One option i have explored is using autoITscript, is there a better approach than that? i feel able to do the whole thing in visual studio would be an ideal way? any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I found that those actions run before installation are best executed via some kind of bootstrapper program. I choose AutoIt for this, because it was so darn felxible and complete. All the other bootstrappers I found were not flexible enough or simply abandoned. Now, months later, I can confirm that AutoIt has been a good choice.